# Vue: Bind click event to dynamically inserted content

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue app which requests some html from an API that contains some blocks like `<div class="play-video">...</div>`

Calling the API with axios via a promise, it is inserted into the dom something like:

`<div v-if="content" v-html="content"></div>`

How can I bind click events to the children with the `.play-video` class? Is it just a matter of watching for `content` to change, and then running vanilla js query selectors to bind to them?

Comment: what about adding ref (https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) to your div which has v-html attr?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use some event delegation by adding a `@click` handler and checking the target element using [`Element.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    content: null
  }),
  methods: {
    handleClick(e) {
      const elt = e.target.closest(".play-video");
      if (elt) {
        console.log("Got a click on .play-video or a child element")
      }
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    // simulate loading content
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.content = `
        <div>
          <p>Some other element</p>
          <button>I'm not part of <code>.play-video</code></button>
          <div class="play-video">
            <p><button>Click me, I am!</button></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        `
    }, 1000)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.21/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-if="content" v-html="content" @click="handleClick"></div>
  <p v-else>Loading...</p>
</div>
```

If you only want to catch click events on the `.play-video` element itself and not any of its children, skip the `.closest()` call and use

```js
if (e.target.matches(".play-video") {
  // ...
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest#polyfill for browser compatibility and a polyfill if required.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Sorry if it was an obvious question but a lot of search results were looking at jQuery.

Comment: @waffl you're welcome. I guess you find jQuery results because jQuery was one of the first frameworks to really make event delegation a first-class citizen