# Adding functionality (javascript?) to a simple html tag in Vue and/or Tiptap?

Tags: javascript, css, vuejs2, vuetify.js, tiptap

How to convert a relatively simple tag to do Javascript or render more complex html? Here's an example of what I try to accomplish:

In this Vue.js SPA, there is a rich text editor (i'm experimenting with Tiptap) enabling users to write small pieces of rich text. The editor has an additional button that can mark a piece of text and apply a tag to it to mark it as a country (similar as marking something bold, only this marks it as a country). Something like this:

```
Lorem ipsum at <span data-country-id="42">Denmark</span>.
```

I have full control over how that tag would look, but I want to keep it short and *front-end agnostic* (so rather no javascript in there).

Required is to allow this span to onclick/onmouseover to either a `v-overlay` or a `v-tooltip`. Thus by activating it an overlay/tooltip pops up with more information about Denmark. I could also imagine I'd route it to a page on Denmark. All of this depending on where the content is shown, so you see how it has to be agnostic.

*If* I would be able to call a javascript function, I would be able to open a `v-overlay` or call a `this.$router.push`. I think this may also allow v-tooltips via an on-activator.

My mind came already came up with these approaches, but I may be way off here.

- Being able to call javascript, somehow.
- The data will be rendered to the screen using the Tiptap editor. Perhaps there are possibilities there?
- ...?

### Update; I think I may have found a solution. How good/bad is this?:

The 'rich text' is shown when a row on a table is clicked. The selected row is stored in `selected`. This is where we render it:

```
<div ref="mycontent" v-html="selected.description_html" @click="handleClick"></div>
```

The `description_html` contains the span mentioned in the question. The handleClick function checks if an element with a data-country-id is clicked, and if so sets a global variable and opens an overlay.

```
handleClick(e) {
   if (e.target.matches('[data-country-id]')) {
       this.country_id = e.srcElement.attributes.getNamedItem("data-country-id").value
       console.log(this.country_id)
       this.olyCountry = true
   }
},
```

A similar method may work for a mouseover. -- I do wonder if I have to remove the eventListener at some point? With inspiration from: [Vue: Bind click event to dynamically inserted content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53877388/vue-bind-click-event-to-dynamically-inserted-content)